# How to Get MYSQL Query into a TextBox?

Tags: c#, mysql

Given the following code How do I get the results of a MYSQL query in C# in to a textbox? I have tried for hours to figure it out - it should be easy I guess. Here's the following code attempt. BTW coming from using procedural PHP I'm really struggling with MYSQL and C#, should I use a different code?:

```
...
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace houseDB1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private string server;
        private string database;
        private string uid;
        private string password;
        private MySqlConnection connection;



        public Form2(string strTextBox)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // richTextBox1.Text = strTextBox;
            int num = int.Parse(strTextBox);



            server = "localhost";
            database = "realestate_db";
            uid = "root";
            password = "";
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter;
            mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT `ID`, `lat` , `long` FROM `house` ", connection);
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);

            richTextBox1.Text = DS.Tables[0].ToString(); // doesn't work

        }

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you're using a TextBox? A GridView would be the normal approach.

For example you could do:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT `ID`, `lat` , `long` FROM `house`;", conn);
conn.Open();
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

da.Fill(dataTable);


GridVIew.DataSource = dataTable;
GridVIew.DataBind();
```

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon.  If the page is a duplicate, flag it as such.  If its not, post the relevant bits to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
DS.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();// gets the first row, first cell
```

So you need to loop the table in order to fill the textbox:

```
string myRichTextTB = "";
for(int i=0; i< DS.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
  for(int j=0; j< 3/*number of the selected columns*/; j++)
  {
    myRichTextTB = myRichTextTB + DS.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should definitely move away from doing what you're currently doing...

It's a dated way of doing things, inefficient (due to the time you waste), and can leave you prone to SQL injection attacks if your queries aren't parametized.

What you need is called **Object Relational Mapping (ORM)**... It's a way of communicating with your database without writing a single line of SQL, or worrying about table names, or column names, or whether the column is a nullable type. You only interact with your C# objects, and the ORM persists the data if you want it to, it generates all that SQL that you are writing by hand behind the scenes...

Your `Customers table` would consist of a collection of `Customer` objects, your `Orders table` would consist of `Order` objects, and you could retrieve all of any given customers `Orders`, because the 'Customer' would have a `Collection<Order>` property which you could navigate to and retrieve, without writing a single line of SQL.

So how do you do it?

First you need to install Entity Framework from NuGet (EntityFramework is an ORM by Microsoft)...

The shortest way of doing that is pressing `CTRL + Q` and typing `Package Manager` and selecting the first option...

Then, type this in to the console....

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
```

After that's done... install [this extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838) which you'll use to reverse engineer your entire database and have it represented in C# classes in your project.